# Nextjs: context undefined in getStaticProps

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

the context from getStaticProps is undefined.
If I console.log the context I get:
`{ locales: undefined, locale: undefined }`

I need the information from the url...
If I try the same with getServerSideProps it is working.
I'm using apollo with nextjs like the example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();

    await apolloClient.query({
        query: PAGE,
        variables: variables,
    });

    console.log(context);
    // { locales: undefined, locale: undefined }
    // !!! need the info from the URL !!!

    return {
        props: {
            initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
        },
        revalidate: 1,
    };
}
```

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

These params doesn’t exist on the `context` Object that’s why you get `undefined`. I assume that you pass them as query parameters to the url. In that case you can get them from the context query param like this:

```
const { locales } = context.query
```

Read more about the params of the `context` Object in the next docs
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps